# Disc2vhd and partitioning 

Tags: vhd, disk2vhd

I am using Disc2Vhd to make a vhd of my drive. Does the tool support partitions? My partitions of C:\ are listed as both drives and volumes. In short, is there any issue **when I select both partitions that make one physical drive**?

Answer (score 0):

According to [**Windows Sysinternals**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx), it does support multiple partitions.

> It will create one VHD for each disk
>   on which selected volumes reside. It
>   preserves the partitioning information
>   of the disk, but only copies the data
>   contents for volumes on the disk that
>   are selected. This enables you to
>   capture just system volumes and
>   exclude data volumes, for example.

Here is a screenshot from the website showing the program in action:

[image]